# Google Data Studio - Multiply Number Ranges by Varied Percentages

Tags: looker-studio

I’m sure I’m doing something stupid here but I’m trying to multiply certain number ranges by certain percentages and keep getting calculation errors. “THEN/ELSE statements cannot contain functions or mathematical operations. CLOSE”

Does anyone know a better way to accomplish this?

My failure is below:

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Ad Budget,"200-9999") THEN SUM(Ad Budget*.30)
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Ad Budget,"10000-14999") THEN SUM(Ad Budget*.25)
ELSE "200" 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) section of the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement in the question, suggests that the `Ad Budget` field is of the **Number** **Semantic Type**, thus, instead of using [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476), **Comparison Operators** (`>=` `<`) would do the trick; in addition, the [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021) included enhancements to **Conditional Expressions** in [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements, thus the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below should do the trick:

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN Ad Budget >= 200 AND Ad Budget < 10000 THEN Ad Budget * 0.30
    WHEN Ad Budget >= 10000 AND Ad Budget < 15000 THEN Ad Budget * 0.25
    ELSE 200 END)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/946cda1f-d2de-446a-8c42-2b421edb65ae) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sULK-RD7nUdW8BGr0ki2S6Dbv7LctIUg4eiU8nOhbos/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]